# Xamarin forms Google authentification

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Google authentification by following this [this link](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin) and using the plugin [Plugin.GoogleClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.GoogleClient)

I have follow all the steps very carefully:
sha Key, keychain on IOs, Auth Google agreement, Firebase.. ButI have 2 errors:

On Andoid :
I have the Error :  GoogleClientBaseException

error : "10:"

On IOS:
I have the Error :  GoogleClientBaseException

error : "There was a problem readind or writing to the application keychain"

A button launch the authentification by calling the function "OnLogGoogle"

Here is the code :

```
IGoogleClientManager _googleService = CrossGoogleClient.Current; //Plugin.GoogleClient


private async  void OnLogGoogle(object senderApp, EventArgs eApp)
{
    _googleService.OnLogin += OnLoginCompleted;
    try
    {
        await _googleService.LoginAsync();
    }
    catch (GoogleClientSignInNetworkErrorException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error1", e.Message, "OK");
    }
    catch (GoogleClientSignInCanceledErrorException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error2", e.Message, "OK");
    }
    catch (GoogleClientSignInInvalidAccountErrorException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error3", e.Message, "OK");
    }
    catch (GoogleClientSignInInternalErrorException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error4", e.Message, "OK");
    }
    catch (GoogleClientNotInitializedErrorException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error5", e.Message, "OK");
    }
    catch (GoogleClientBaseException e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error6", e.Message, "OK");

    } 

}



private void OnLoginCompleted(object sender, GoogleClientResultEventArgs<GoogleUser> loginEventArgs)
        {
            if (loginEventArgs.Data != null)
            {
                GoogleUser googleUser = loginEventArgs.Data;
              /*  User.Name = googleUser.Name;
                User.Email = googleUser.Email;
                User.Picture = googleUser.Picture;
                var GivenName = googleUser.GivenName;
                var FamilyName = googleUser.FamilyName;*/


                // Log the current User email
                Console.WriteLine("email "+ googleUser.Email);
                

                var token = CrossGoogleClient.Current.AccessToken;
                var Token = token;
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", loginEventArgs.Message, "OK");
            }

            _googleService.OnLogin -= OnLoginCompleted;

        }
```

Comment: Hi, from shared link, it not supports for xamarin forms. You could have a look at this sample. https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Google-Login-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: Google no Longer allow Webview authentification